# How to flip this clipper design

Tags: flutter, customclipper

I want to flip this design as vertically. In here curves position is in bottom I want this curve to position in top. So which value should I change? I have shared my picture and code down below.

[image]

```
class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    double x = 0;
    double y = size.height;
    double yControlPoint = size.height * .88;
    double increment = size.width / 15;

    while (x < size.width) {
      path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x + increment / 2, yControlPoint, x + increment, y);
      x += increment;
    }

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, 0);

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double yControlPoint = size.height - size.height * .88;
    double increment = size.width / 15;

    while (x < size.width) {
      path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x + increment / 2, yControlPoint, x + increment, y);
      x += increment;
    }

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```